# if item in list match item in list from child element in dictionary

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x, iteration

brand new to python and stumped all ready, would appreciate a hand.

```
testn1 = {'names':('tn1_name1','tn1_name2','tn1_name3'),'exts':('.log','.txt')}
testn2 = {'names':('tn2_name1'),'exts':('.nfo')}
testnames = {1:testn1,2:testn1}

directory = 'C:\\temp\\root\\'

for subdir in os.listdir(directory):

  # check if name of sub directory matches the name in any of the dicts in testnames[testn*]['names']
  if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(directory, subdir)) and [subdir in subdir.lower() in testnames[testn1]['names']]: # this  works but need to iterate through all dicts
    print(subdir)

    # if the a dir name matches do a recursive search for all filenames that exist in the same dict with the corresponding extensions
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(os.path.join(directory, subdir)):
      for file in filenames:
        if file.endswith(testnames[testn1]['exts']): # this works but need to match with corresponding folder 
          print(file)
```

I thought i'd be able to do something like this but i'm sure my understanding of python isn't were it needs to be.

```
if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(directory, subdir)) and [subdir in subdir.lower() in [for testnames[key]['names'] in key, value in testnames.items()]]:
```

I'm hoping to keep it structured this way but would be open to anything.

EDIT: I ended up going with...

```
if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(directory, subdir)) and [i for i in testnames.values() if subdir.lower() in i['names']]:
```

thanks to @pzp1997 for the headsup on .values()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did it!

```
if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(directory, subdir)) and [i for i in testnames.values() if subdir.lower() in i['names']]:
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you want, but I think this is it:

```
if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(directory, subdir)) and subdir.lower() in [i['names'] for i in testnames.values()]
```

Comment: thanks pzp, it doesn't seem to return any results, i've modified my post hopefully it clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

What about this instead?

```
testn1 = {'names':('tn1_name1','tn1_name2','tn1_name3'),'exts':('.log','.txt')}
testn2 = {'names':('tn2_name1'),'exts':('.nfo')}
testnames = {1:testn1,2:testn1}

directory = 'C:\\temp\\root\\'

for dirname, _, filenames in os.walk(directory):
    the_dir =  os.path.split(dirname)[-1]
    for testn in testnames.itervalues():
        if the_dir in testn['names']:
            for file in filenames:
                _, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
                if ext in testn['exts']:
                    print the_dir, file
```

Comment: there were a few bugs but i've now tested it ... not sure exactly you were trying to do though

Comment: Hi Julien, haven't gone down this path yet, I want to see if i can simply tweak that single line first. Will revist if all else fails. thanks